# How to properly add items to database and separation of concerns

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I'm trying to create a post to add an entity to my database. I fear that I might be mixing up data and view layers. I'm extremely unfamiliar with design patterns and the repository pattern is killing me.

This is a bit of code from my controller.

```
[HttpPost("CreateArtItem/{createArtItemRequest}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ArtItem>> Put(CreateArtItemRequest createArtItemRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                if (createArtItemRequest != null)
                {
                    ArtItem artItem = new ArtItem()
                    {
                        //mapping
                    };

                    _artRepository.AddArtItem(artItem);
                    _artRepository.Add(artItem);
                    if (await _artRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
                    {
                        return Created(artItem.Id.ToString(), artItem);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Database failure.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Database failure.");
            }
        }
```

I'd highly appreciate it if someone could explain to me how the different layers work, what the data operations are, and if this is a proper implementation of post.

I'm following a guide on pluralsight and the dude teaching is doing something similar.

[image: pluralsight]

Comment: There are so many ways to skin this cat, it will be impossible to have one answer here, that's probably why this question will be closed as "too broad". Short answer I can give "It all depends on your case".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, in order to creating a new entity and saving it into the database, you are using:

- a ***repository layer*** that decouples your model (business entities of your application domain) from your database schema objects (tables, views, etc..). Your model is **`ArtItem`**
- and a ***view-model object***, **`CreateArtItemRequest`**, that decouples your ui from your business model.

The operations on data that you have to implement are:

1. mapping from **`CreateArtItemRequest`** to **`ArtItem`**
2. method **`Add()`** of your repository
3. method **`SaveChangesAsync()`**

From your example I see that you use 2 methods to add the new entity to your repository (that seems to be a property, or field, member of your class controller) and that you call twice the method of your repostory to add the created new entity, I think it is a sort of error, anyway it needs only one call to add the entity to the repository.

You should to know how repositories work, and how they implement their operations on data (`Add`, `Save`, `Query`, etc..).

Comment: Oh, yeah, the 2 add methods are because I was messing around with inheritence to figure out how to create a more generic repository. Aside from that, am I supposed to do the mapping inside a repository method, or inside the controller?

Comment: In the example from pluralsight you provided gets used a mapper component (eg. Automapper) but you can use also a simple method into view model object that returns an entity object setted with its values